# How to get the min and max value from a dbcontext

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I am storing sensor data in a sql database. Each entry has a device_id, timestamp, value and some other properties.

I want to implement a webapi function which returns the first and last event that i have received from a sensor device. So my serialized DTO should be something like this:
`{ "start": <timestamp:long>, "end": <timestamp:long>, "deviceid": <someid:string>}`

I am using Entityframework Core to access my database. I can get a list of unique device id's without any problems. If i try to get the min or max value of the timestamp per device, my dbcontext throws an invalid operation exception.

I tried several things like this:

```
var deviceList=_context.Data.Select(d=>d.DeviceId).Distinct();
foreach(string deviceId in deviceList)
{
   var max = _context.Data.Where(g=>g.DeviceId==deviceId).Max(c=>c.Timestamp);
   var min ...
}
```

This snippet throws an invalid operation exception from the clr. As far as i understand this, it creates a statement which is not executed on the server side. My question is how i can create a query that requests the min and max value (per device) on a dbcontext? Also i would like know what the recommended way is to implement this, so that it is not executed on the client side.

Thank you Werner.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I would recommend not using EF Core for production unless you application is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting your `_context.Data` refers to all the records (rows) in table. and you can use `group by` to get it. try below one, and let me know if it works for you.

First we group by the device id, and then for each group, we get the min and max timespan.

```
var data = _context.Data.GroupBy(f => f.deviceId)
    .Select(g =>
                new { 
                      deviceId = g.Key,
                      start = g.Min(r=>r.timestamp),
                      end = g.Max(r=>r.timestamp)
                     }
           );
```

Comment: Yes, Data is the name of my DbSet in my DbContext. Unfortunatly, this throws also an exception:

Comment: Connection id "0HLBULVGGJSBN", Request id "0HLBULVGGJSBN:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Warning as error exception for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning': The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([f].DeviceId, [f])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. To suppress this Exception use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API.

Comment: Are you using EF Core? EF Core doesn't support server side Group By and won't until v2.1 is released.

Comment: Hmm, yes i am using EF Core. I was not aware that this is not supported. I will use a raw sql statement to implement my query and accept this answer as there is no solution available yet. Thank you!

Comment: @NetMage did you notice in question is doing `_context.Data.select` mean he is looping complete collection, and so do I.  yes its not group at server, in fact it pulls all object and then do group by,

Comment: That is true, but see last line of question.